Using local images with filepaths defined in markdown - AstroJS
I've been wrestling with an issue I haven't been able to solve re: using local images from markdown files. My markdown file has filepaths in it, and I have been trying to get past an error that comes up from the way Astro optimizes images. I want to use Astros optimization feature, and it seems from the doc that using filepaths should be possible, but I haven't been able to do it properly.
My latest attempt uses a schema as shown in the docs
import {defineCollection, z} from "astro:content";

const tourCollection = defineCollection({
    schema: ({ image }) => z.object({
      title: z.string(),
      description: z.string(),
      main: z.object({
        content: z.string(),
        imgMain: image().refine(img => img.width >= 1080, {
          message: "Main image must be at least 1080 pixels wide",
        }),
        imgAlt: z.string(),
      })
}),

And then my collection of markdown files with image filepaths are parsed and displayed, but even using this scheme I keep encountering the same error.
[ERROR] [LocalImageUsedWrongly] Image's and getImage's src parameter must be an imported image or an URL, it cannot be a string filepath. Received ../images/product-image-1.avif.
Here is a sample of my markdown, and my actual astro code for reference.
Markdown
title: "SF-TB T845"
description: "Machine Screws"
main:
  id: 1
  content: |
    Introducing the SF-TB T845 – your go-to solution for precision fastening in machinery and equipment. This comprehensive set of machine screws is meticulously crafted to meet the stringent demands of industrial applications, ensuring secure and reliable fastening.
  imgCard: "../images/product-image-1.avif"
  imgMain: "../images/product-image-1.avif"
  imgAlt: "Mockup boxes of machine screws set"

Code
---
// Import section components
import MainLayout from "@/layouts/MainLayout.astro";
import ProductTabBtn from "@/components/ui/buttons/ProductTabBtn.astro";
import PrimaryCTA from "@/components/ui/buttons/PrimaryCTA.astro";
import { Image } from "astro:assets";
import { getCollection} from "astro:content";
import { collections } from "./collections";
import { SITE } from "@/data_files/constants";


// Global declaration for gsap animation library
declare global {
  interface Window {
    gsap: any;
  }
}


// This gets the static paths for all the unique products
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const productEntries = await getCollection("tours");
  return productEntries.map((product) => ({
    params: { slug: product.slug },
    props: { product },
  }));
}

const { product } = Astro.props;

const pageTitle: string = `${product.data.title} | ${SITE.title}`;
---


<MainLayout
  title={pageTitle}
>
  <div id="overlay" class="fixed inset-0 bg-neutral-200 dark:bg-neutral-800">
  </div>

  <section
    class="mx-auto flex max-w-[85rem] flex-col px-4 py-10 sm:px-6 lg:px-8 lg:py-14 2xl:max-w-full"
  >
    <div>
      <p
        id="fadeText"
        class="mb-8 max-w-prose text-pretty font-light text-neutral-700 dark:text-neutral-300 sm:text-xl"
      >
        {product.data.main.content}
      </p>
    </div>
    <div
      class="flex flex-col items-center justify-between space-y-4 sm:flex-row sm:space-y-0"
    >
      <div id="fadeInUp">
        <h1
          class="block text-4xl font-bold tracking-tighter text-neutral-800 dark:text-neutral-200 sm:text-5xl md:text-6xl lg:text-7xl"
        >
          {product.data.title}
        </h1>
        <p class="text-lg text-neutral-600 dark:text-neutral-400">
          {product.data.description}
        </p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Image
          id="fadeInMoveRight"
          src={product.data.main.imgMain}
          class="w-[600px]"
          alt={product.data.main.imgAlt}
          format={"avif"}
          loading={"eager"}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

I have tried using Vite import.meta.glob() as I saw in a 2 year old blog post on the same issue, changing the file location to something closer, as well as the schema I am now using. I have also tried using markdown's !()[] but this doesn't seem to work as I need it to be accessible as a property.

There shouldn't be an @ in imgMain: "@/images/product-image-1.avif"

I know, but I'm getting the error on the first line. I saw it in another project so I tried it.

Have you defined the scheme at content\tour\config.ts (I assume your collection is named tour)? I made the same mistake at first and had the same issue, you simply would need to move the file to content\config.ts - there is only one config file for all collections.
